# Is there a way to use syntactic sugar to build lists of existential types?

Tags: haskell, syntactic-sugar, existential-type, overloaded-lists

Consider a list-like type like this one:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ExistentialQuantification #-}

data ShowList = Nil | forall a. Show a => a :* ShowList
infixr 5 :*

myShowList :: ShowList
myShowList = 'x' :* () :* Nil
```

I'd like to be able to use syntactic sugar to build these lists like this:

```
myShowList :: ShowList
myShowList = ['x', ()]
```

But even with `RebindableSyntax` and `OverloadedLists`, it looks like I'm stuck going through the built-in list type, which messes me up by trying to unify the types of all the elements:

```
$ ghci -XRebindableSyntax -XOverloadedLists
GHCi, version 9.2.1: https://www.haskell.org/ghc/  :? for help
ghci> fromListN = fromListN
ghci> myShowList = ['x', ()]

<interactive>:2:20: error:
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.Types.Char’
                  with actual type ‘()’
    • In the expression: ()
      In the expression: ['x', ()]
      In an equation for ‘myShowList’: myShowList = ['x', ()]
ghci> :info []
type [] :: * -> *
data [] a = [] | a : [a]
        -- Defined in ‘GHC.Types’
ghci>
```

Is there any way around this, or am I stuck writing these out without sugar?

Comment: It seems that `RebindableSyntax` and `OverloadedLists` both merely customize the dispatching of the function call, the input being fed to said functions are still regular lists. Perhaps TemplateHaskell is the closest route here?

Comment: Yeah, I think what @Chase is saying is correct. The docs for RebindableSyntax don't say anything about `:` and `[]` being rebindable. The docs for `OverloadedLists` mention that only `toList`, `fromList` and `fromListN` are rebindable, so you could rebind `fromListN` to whatever you want, but the desugaring of a list literal is always going to build an actual list and then pass that to `fromListN`, so I don't think that this can be done.

Comment: Though if you really wanted a different syntax, I guess that you could abuse `QualifiedDo` and get something like `ShowList.do 'x' ; () ; Nil`, but that doesn't appear to be worth it.